# Cambio de orden en nav por culpa del css

Tags: html, css, scss

tengo un problema con mi navegador y es que cuando lo pongo en la posición que quiero (al lado derecho) se cambia todo el orden que yo le he dado en el Html. ¿Hay alguna solución? Os dejo el código aquí y muchas gracias de antemano.

```
HTML   <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <!-- error, no tiene el mismo orden que aquí que en la web  -->
            <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>

SCSS-CSS  nav{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    ul{
        list-style: none;
        padding: 25px;

        li{
            text-align: right;
            a{
               float: right;
               font-family: Lato;
               font-size: 16px;
               color:$whit;
               display: inline;
               margin: 0 40px;
               padding: 10px;
               border: 2px solid;
               width: 150px; 
               text-align: center;
                a .work{
                    margin-left: 30px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que le estas dando un float:left al nav, y al a le estas dando un float:right.
Por eso esta del otro lado solo necesitas cambiar el float:right a float:left del a

```css
    nav{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
    }

  ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 25px;
}
    li{
      text-align: right;
}
      a{
        float: left;
        font-family: Lato;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #262626;
        display: inline;
        margin: 0 40px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 2px solid;
        width: 150px;
        text-align: center;
}
        a .work{
          margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <!-- error, no tiene el mismo orden que aquí que en la web  -->
            <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
```